# MiniProfiler .Ignore() extension method does not disable profiling

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, mvc-mini-profiler, miniprofiler

I have a method with a portion of code I want to ignore from profiling when using MiniProfiler.

As from documentation, the extension method that does this is `.Ignore()`, that when used in a `using` statement should disable profiling for the duration.

Unfortunately I'm not getting the results as expected. Suppose I have this method structure:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> FirstMethod()
{
    using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("FirstMethod"))
    {
        IActionResult result = this.SecondMethod();
        
        using (MiniProfiler.Current.Ignore())
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100); 
        }

        return result;
    }
}

internal virtual IActionResult SecondMethod()
{
    using (MiniProfiler.Current.CustomTiming("SQL", "QuerySecondMethod"))
    {
        // Some data logic
    }
}
```

What I expected is that on profiler the `FirstMethod` step duration and the `SecondMethod` custom timing would be approximately the same, since `FirstMethod` only calls `SecondMethod` and is ignoring the `Thread.Sleep()`.

But I keep getting that `FirstMethod` duration is 100 milliseconds longer than `SecondMethod`, which makes it looks like the `Ignore` is not really disabling the profiler for the code inside it.

What am I doing wrong? Am I misunderstanding the documentation and purpose of the `Ignore` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.Ignore()` method is for suppressing the code inside it, not the overall.

If you want to stop and throw away the profiler, your options are:

```
MiniProfiler.Current.Stop(discardResults: true);
```

For more details, you can [check this issue](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/issues/480) in github.